# IndentationError al crear una matriz de valores aleatorios

Tags: python, python-3.7

Estoy haciendo una matriz con valores aleatorios entre -9 y 9, más al dar las instrucciones:

```
def crearMatriz (filas, columna):
return [[float(R.randint(-9,9)) for j in range(columnas)] for i in range(filas)]
```

Me marca:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    return [[float(R.randint(-9,9)) for j in range(columnas)] for i in range(filas)]
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: En python, ya que no hay llaves para delimitar donde empieza y termina un bloque (por ejemplo, cuál es el cuerpo de una función), se usa la indentación como parte de la sintaxis. Cada vez que inicias un nuevo bloque (por ejemplo el cuerpo de una función) debes "indentar" la línea (poner cuatro espacios por delante). Todas las líneas de un mismo bloque han de tener la misma indentación, a menos que alguna de ellas inicie un nuevo sub-bloque (un bucle, un if) en cuyo caso las líneas siguientes irán más indentadas.

Comment: Aparte de lo que ha dicho abulafia, en los parámetros de la función has puesto 'columna', mientras que dentro de la función utilizas 'columnas'. Deberías igualarlos para que te funcione, y con esos dos cambios ya te creará la matriz.

Answer (score 0):

A diferencia de lenguajes como C, en Python no resulta intuitivo el proceso de creación de una matriz. En este caso lo puedes hacer utilizando listas, por ejemplo:

```
import random

numero_filas = 4
numero_columnas = 4
matriz = []
for i in range(numero_filas):
    matriz.append([])
    for j in range(numero_columnas):
        matriz[i].append(random.randint(-9,9))

print (matriz)
```